# Git & Github: can't push or clone via SSH or Https, the requested URL returned error 400

Tags: git, github

I have created a new Github repo but it seems like I can't push to it or clone it, when I try to push via SSH key I get this error:

```
fatal: remote error: 
   is not a valid repository name
  Visit https://support.github.com/ for help
```

and when trying Https I get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/name/repo.git~/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

I have tried to push and clone an old repo and It worked normally but it is not working with new repos.
I tried also to delete my credentials from credential manager but it doesn't work,
I tried to change the SSH keys on my pc and my Github account and it also doesn't work,

Comment: Run `git remote -v` to show the URLs stored in your settings. At least one of them has at least some bad characters in it. Use `git remote set-url` or `git config --edit` to fix the stored URL(s).

Answer (score 0):

For HTTPS, try:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/name/repo.git
                                                         ^^^
                                                    (no trailing ~/)
```

For SSH:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:name/repo.git
```